# MS Dynamics CRM 2015 - How to use fetch xml in custom workflow?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2015

I am trying to use fetch xml in a custom work but I am unable to do so successfully.

Requirement:
I have added banner on case entity and display information on Case banner html page using fetch xml successfully. I need to use the same fetch xml in custom workflow and get the result. Based on result, I need to create the task activity on workflow.

I am using the fetch xml below on custom workflow.

```
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="true" aggregate="true">
<entity name="contact">
<attribute name="contactid" alias="vulnerableInformant" aggregate="count" />
<link-entity name="new_contactbanneritem" from="new_contactid" to="contactid" alias="aa">
  <filter type="and">
    <condition attribute="new_category" operator="eq" value="Vulnerable Person" />
  </filter>
</link-entity>
<link-entity name="incident" from="customerid" to="contactid" alias="ab">
  <filter type="and">
   <condition attribute="statecode" value="0" operator="eq"/>
   <condition attribute="incidentid" value="$id" operator="eq"/>
  </filter>
</link-entity>
</entity>
</fetch>
```

Case entity HTML Banner query:

I have called the below line on case banner HTML page using above fetch xml.

```
<td class="label" data-bind="visible: vulnerableInformant() > 0">Additional Support-Informant</td>
```

Comment: we will need more information to assist. 1) I don't follow this question at all - what does fetchXML have to do with custom workflow and case entity HTML - maybe if you explain what you are trying to accomplish from a functional perspective, it would be more clear AND 2) please post the following: What have you tried (where is the fetchXML you said you posted)?  What is the behavior of your current attempt?

Comment: Thank you Joseph. I have resolved the problem. Able to use fetch xml on custom workflow and achieved my requirement output.

Comment: Can you please post your answer and mark it as the answer so this doesn't show up as an unanswered question?